# T-SQL: Any way to rollback after DBCC CHECKCONTRAINTS?

Tags: t-sql, transactions, constraints

I have a stored procedure that starts a transactions. Inside it, I disable some of the constraints. I modify the data. And then enable the constraints.
What I want is to rollback if the data in inconsistent in the end of the SP (prior to calling commit of course).

Currently I run DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS in the end to see what was broken.
But can I just rollback when DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS outputs any data?

Or better: Can the DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS raise error if any of the constraints are broken?

Comment: I don't get it. Why disable the constraints and then try to manually check them yourself? Just leave them enabled and CATCH/ROLLBACK on that error.

Comment: Because I do some data operations that break constrains inside SP. After SP finishes, all should be OK.

Comment: I can't say for sure without all the details, but that sounds like a case of doing the operations in the wrong order.

Comment: Its a huge data import SP, that breaks relationships for a while. And imports new data (inserts, udpates, deletes) step by step. Let's assume it is doing it this way for a reason. Is there any way to make DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINS raising error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS, when you enable the constraints again, use the `WITH CHECK` option.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT YourConstraint;
```

If there is a violation, you'll get an error like:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 15
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "YourConstraint". The conflict occurred in database "YourDatabase", table "YourTable", column 'YourColumn'.
```

Use the sample code below for a simple demonstration.

```
use tempdb
go

create table a (
    id int primary key
)

create table b (
    id int
) 

alter table b add constraint x foreign key (id) references a(id)

alter table b nocheck constraint x

insert into b (id) values (1)

alter table b with check check constraint x
go

drop table b
drop table a
go
```